# Inherent way to save web page source

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have read a lot of answers regarding web scraping that talk about BeautifulSoup, Scrapy e.t.c. to perform web scraping.

Is there a way to do the equivalent of saving a page's source from a web brower?

That is, is there a way in Python to point it at a website and get it to save the page's source to a text file with just the standard Python modules?

Here is where I got to:

```
import urllib

f = open('webpage.txt', 'w')
html = urllib.urlopen("http://www.somewebpage.com")

#somehow save the web page source

f.close()
```

Not much I know - but looking for code to actually pull the source of the page so I can write it. I gather that urlopen just makes a connection.

Perhaps there is a readlines() equivalent for reading lines of a web page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Thanks! Am still very new to the site so sorry if I approached this the wrong way. Will add some code of where I got to :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may try `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')

page_content = page.read()

with open('page_content.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content)
```

Comment: To avoid encoding problems use `with open('page_content.html', 'wb') as fid:`

Answer (score 2):

Updated code, for Python 3 (where urllib2 is deprecated):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
with open('page_content.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(html)
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not HTTPResponse

Answer (score 1):

Answer from SoHei will not work because it's missing html.read() and the file must be opened with 'wb' parameter instead of just a 'w'. The 'b' indicates that data will be written in binary mode (since .read() returns sequence of bytes). 
The fully working code is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
page_content = html.read()
with open('page_content.html', 'wb') as fid:
     fid.write(page_content)
```

Comment: This does not retrieve the same content as when I navigate to my target page and "view page source" - not sure if that is a problem unique to the page I am viewing (requires logon and page source has scripts and embedded json that don't show when read and saved as above).