# Download an entire webpage?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

When I right-click on a page in my browser, I can "Save Page As", saving the entire webpage including images, css, and js.
I've seen questions answered on [downloading a page's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332192/inherent-way-to-save-web-page-source), but this only retrieves the HTML. Is there a solution with urllib2, requests, or any other library, to downloading the complete page?

Comment: with `urllib2`, `requests` you have to find in HTML all urls to images, css, js and download it manually.

Comment: BTW: `wget -p --convert-links http://www.server.com/dir/page.html` - wikipwdia: [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)

Comment: the thing that you are looking for is more like a selenium \ splash library which "render" the whole website and let you save it (they are using browser drivers to parse the data.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) coupled with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to achieve this.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

URL = 'https://example.com'

# open page with selenium
# (first need to download Chrome webdriver, or a firefox webdriver, etc)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

# open 'Save as...' to save html and assets
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite('your_filename' + '.html')
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966809/4420129)